# Kotlin Error : 'public' function exposes its 'public/*package*/' return type argument

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, extends

I am new to Kotlin and trying out to write some project using the language.
I am using Java library and extending a class from the library in my project and I am seeing this error message.

```
'public' function exposes its 'public/*package*/' return type argument FooSettings
```

I understand what the problem is, but I am not sure how to fix it in Kotlin since I am still trying get familiar with Kotlin.
I can see that Kotlin is being smart and only trying to return of type that extends `FooSettings`. However the problem is `FooSettings` is package public only which means that I cannot access if in my Kotlin project.

I did some research about Kotlin generics and use of `in` or `out` but I wasn't able to fix the problem.

Is there any work around that I can do in my Kotlin project to fix the error I am seeing?

### Code snippet

**This is sample of Java library class:**
Note, I have no way to changing the implementation of the library. I must use this Library and extend it in Kotlin.

It seems odd to me that the java library is written such a way and expect it to be overridden but that is question for another day.

```java
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class ClassA {
    public List<FooBuilder<?>> getBuilder(Foo foo) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}

public class Foo {
}

public abstract class FooBuilder<U extends FooBuilder.FooSettings> {
    // implementation of Class
    abstract static class FooSettings {
        // implementation of Class
    }
}
```

**Normally Java classes would override the method like such:**

```
import java.util.List;

public class MyJavaClassA extends ClassA {
    @Override public List<FooBuilder<?>> getBuilder(final Foo foo) {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

**But I am trying to write in Kotlin such that it looks like**: Reminder that this Kotlin is depending on the Java library and does not have access to package public classes.

```kotlin
class MyKotlinClassA : ClassA() {
    override fun getBuilder(foo: Foo): MutableList<FooBuilder<*>> {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

This causes error

```
'public' function exposes its 'public/*package*/' return type argument FooSettings
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I presume that by "package public" you meant "package private"? In your example, `FooBuilder.FooSettings` has no visibility modifier so uses the Java default of package private. Assuming that's what you meant...

You will be able to access the package private class, `FooSettings`, in your Kotlin code, but only if you put that Kotlin code in a package matching the one where `FooSettings` is declared.

You'll still get the same compilation error, but that's not because you can't access the type: it's because you're trying to use it in a context which is more visible than the type's declaration. i.e. you're trying to take a package private type and use it as part of a public method's signature, which isn't allowed. To get round that problem you need to mark your Kotlin class as `internal`.

It's might also be worth mentioning that `internal` for Kotlin means it's visible in that **module**, not in that **package**. This is all explained in more detail [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html).

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks. Marking the subclass `internal` also resolves `public subclass exposes its public/*package*/ supertype [type name]`

Comment: The easiest way I have found to think of it is that Kotlin is a separate package, but with the same name. That means a class in Java needs to be a public class for Kotlin to see it. Kotlin, on the other hand, is better at being backwards compatible.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was getting this error because I was importing a kotlin class variable from another java file which raised because of the auto conversion from java to kotlin by Android Studio.

I was able to fix it by changing all the references of the variable in the java file to its setters and getters.

eg:

```
// kotlin file
internal open class BubbleBaseLayout : FrameLayout {
    var windowManager: WindowManager? = null
    lateinit var viewParams: WindowManager.LayoutParams
    // defined here
    var layoutCoordinator: BubblesLayoutCoordinator? = null
    
    // ...
}
```

```java
// Java file
    // This variable
    if (layoutCoordinator != null) { ... }
```

Needs to be changed to

```
// layoutCoordinator to getlayoutCoordinator everywhere
    if(getlayoutCoordinator() != null){ ... }
```